# Android library creation

Tags: android, android-library, aar

I am going to create an Android library. The library should make a Rest API request. If I made a regular application I would use Retrofit for this purposes. I am interested in library making best practices:

1. Can I use other libraries like Retrofit and Gson or I should use something lower level like OkHttp?
2. If I use other libraries inside my one should I use latest versions or better to use old ones?
3. If Retrofit in my library newer then Retrofit in app module will it produce any errors?

Comment: `Can I use other libraries like Retrofit and Gson or I should use something lower level like OkHttp?` really depends on what version of apps you want to support i guess

Comment: `If I use other libraries inside my one should I use latest versions or better to use old ones?` can't really think of a situation where older libraries would work better, i could be wrong